# Node.js execute .lnc file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, child-process

There was a problem when opening a shortcut (.lnk) through node.js. How should I open it?

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var runLibreOffice =function(){
    exec('D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
runLibreOffice();
```

Comment: Hello, this script shows any error? Have you seen https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback ? 
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('node', ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {})

Comment: Hey. The script normally opens .exe files. But
with .lnc problems with him. Shows this error:

{ Error: Command failed: D:\Downloads\bot\botgo.lnk
"D:\Downloads\bot\botgo" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk' }

Comment: Check this question and response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497183/spawning-a-lnk-windows-shortcut-with-node-js-gives-unknown-error

Comment: More information about this problem https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node

Comment: At the moment I got this code: spawn('D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk', {shell : true}, function(err, data). When you run the file, nothing is displayed in the console and does not start.

Answer (score 0):

maybe with windows-shortcuts you can read and execute de .exe into the shortcut.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-shortcuts

```
ws.query("C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Windows Update.lnk", console.log);

/* From console:
null { expanded:
   { args: 'startmenu',
     workingDir: 'C:\\Windows\\system32',
     icon: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\wucltux.dll' },
  target: '%windir%\\system32\\wuapp.exe',
  args: 'startmenu',
  workingDir: '%windir%\\system32',
  runStyle: 1,
  icon: '%windir%\\system32\\wucltux.dll',
  iconIndex: '0',
  hotkey: 0,
  desc: 'Delivers software updates and drivers, and provides automatic updating options.' }
*/
```